# How to calculate the ratio of records based on values of two columns distinctly with the inner join of another table?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ssms

I'm developing a new analyst feature for an internal tool my company will (hopefully if I do well) use.

For simplicity sake, let's say we have

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    ProductID varchar,
    Description varchar,
   ....
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    ProductID varchar,
    Bought date,
    Returned date,
   ....
);
```

The tables would look something like this:

Products

| ProductID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| SPO00 | Sports product 1 |
| SPO01 | Sports product 2 |
| SPO02 | Sports product 3 |
| ELE00 | Electronics product 1 |
| ELE02 | Electronics product 2 |

Orders

| ProductID | Bought | Returned |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ELE00 | 2021-01-05 | 2021-01-07 |
| SPO00 | 2021-01-01 | NULL |
| SPO00 | 2021-01-05 | 2021-01-08 |
| SPO00 | 2021-01-08 | NULL |
| SPO01 | 2021-01-10 | NULL |
| SPO01 | 2021-01-15 | NULL |
| SPO02 | 2021-01-18 | 2021-01-20 |

I'd like to make a request to our DB and retrieve the description of specific products, and the percentage of bought products that are eventually returned.

I'd would also like to add specific parameters to the query, for example select only orders from beginning of the year as well as only the products from a specific department, for example.

So, it would looks something like this:

| Description | ratio returned |
| --- | --- |
| Sports product 1 | 0.33 |
| Sports product 2 | 0.00 |
| Sports product 3 | 1.0 |

So, the products table might have product lines of electronics and sports and ProductID would be ELE00-ELE05 and SPO00-SPO03, respectively.

The above table is grabbing all products that have ProductID with SPO prefix and getting that specific products bought and returned ratio.

I've only been able to get the specific products, but the returned ratio is the same for each row. I think because its not doing the ratio calculation for each distinct product. I think its doing one overall ratio calculation and displaying that for each product.

Here is the query I've tried.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product.Description, (CAST((SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM Orders WHERE(ProductID like 'SPO%' AND Returned > '2021-01-01') AS FLOAT)) / (CAST((SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM Orders WHERE (ProductID like 'SPO%' AND Bought > '2021-01-01') AS FLOAT)) AS returnedRatio
FROM Product INNER JOIN
Orders ON Orders.ProductID = Product.ProductID
```

I'm thinking I might need to do a nested query to get the ratios for each product and then get the description?

All help would be greatly appreciated because I've never done very complex queries so I'm still learning.

Comment: that won't be hard, but I need one thing from you, could you please give some sample data? since you said product id is int, but you stored 'SPO' inside it, so i'm not sure what the data looks like

Comment: @JiachengGao Hi, sorry about that. It should actually be stored as a varchar(8). The reason I used sample data is because the actual tables that I need to retrieve from have about 80 columns and in my attempt to simplify my problem I overlooked that.
I have edited the main post to reflect this.

Comment: @JiachengGao I also added some tables to the post regarding what the tables might look like with data in them.

Comment: I used your data, and check the query I sent below, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

I used a `case` expression inside the `count()` function to count the number of returned products.

The `* 1.0` turns the integer division into a decimal division without explicitly casting.

**Sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    ProductID nvarchar(5),
    Description nvarchar(50)
);

insert into Products (ProductId, Description) values
('SPO00',   'Sports product 1'),
('SPO01',   'Sports product 2'),
('SPO02',   'Sports product 3'),
('ELE00',   'Electronics product 1'),
('ELE02',   'Electronics product 2');

CREATE TABLE Orders (
    ProductID nvarchar(5),
    Bought date,
    Returned date
);

insert into Orders (ProductID, Bought, Returned) values
('ELE00', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-07'),
('SPO00', '2021-01-01', NULL),
('SPO00', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-08'),
('SPO00', '2021-01-08', NULL),
('SPO01', '2021-01-10', NULL),
('SPO01', '2021-01-15', NULL),
('SPO02', '2021-01-18', '2021-01-20');
```

**Solution**

```
select p.Description,
       count(case when o.Returned is not null then 1 end) as ReturnCount,
       count(1) TotalCount,
       count(case when o.Returned is not null then 1 end) * 1.0 / count(1) as ReturnRatio
from Products p
join Orders o
  on o.ProductID = p.ProductID
where p.ProductID like 'SPO%'
  and o.Bought >= '2021-01-01'
group by p.Description;
```

**Result**

```
Description       ReturnCount  TotalCount  ReturnRatio
----------------  -----------  ----------  --------------
Sports product 1  1            3           0.333333333333
Sports product 2  0            2           0
Sports product 3  1            1           1
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e4729/7) to see things in action.

Comment: This was helpful...when I try and use it with my actual database the returnCount is equal with totalCount and is thus throwing off the ratio, but this will be accepted answer because it solves the question I asked. I believe I will be able to use what this answer gave me and apply it to my real-world situation.